# Make PHP wait until the JSON is loaded?

Tags: php, ajax, json, file-get-contents

I have this:

```
<?php 
$phpjson = (file_get_contents('icons_ajax.php?alls'), true);
var_dump ($phpjson);
 ?>
```

It returns:

**Warning: file_get_contents(icons_ajax.php?alls) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/flamenco/public_html/icons_cogo_20.php on line 184
NULL**

I suspect this is because the JSON is not loaded yet.

Any way to make PHP wait until the JSON is loaded?

This is the test page with the problem: http://flamencopeko.net/icons_cogo_20.php

Comment: Can you try using `$phpjson = file_get_contents('http://flamencopeko.net/icons_ajax.php?alls')`? You could also simply copy the code over from that file and have `$_GET['alls']` not empty.

Comment: Dave Chen: Yes. Tried only that one sentence too. Didn't work. I don't understand what 'You could also simply copy the code over from that file and have $_GET['alls'] not empty.' means.

Comment: Since `/icons_ajax.php` is on the same server, why not just open that file up, and copy the code responsible for the json into `icons_cogo_20.php`?

Comment: Dave: Ok. I understand now. I don't know exactly why, but JSON is very often in a file of its own. There's even a .json extension (that I don't use). I also plan to use this this file with only the url it contains changed, for several pages. But yeah, I'm not having rapid success here tonight, despite all you very kind souls trying to help me, so I'll give that a try too. Thanks. Now that I've thought about it, your suggestion is very good. Almost bound to tell us a bit more about what is (not) going on.

Comment: Instant success. :) See http://flamencopeko.net/icons_cogo_ajax.php Now I'll try to get only the alls part. And if I manage that, next step would be to try to use it.

Comment: Any idea on how to get the alls array from php now that we have it in the file? Source: http://flamencopeko.net/icons_cogo_ajax.txt

Comment: Made a new post for that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372250/have-json-object-printed-with-js-and-php-in-file-need-to-get-only-array

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as “JSON is not loaded yet”.
`var_dump` won’t get called until `file_get_contents` is finished.
Your error is as it says: there is no such file. Try to provide the full path.

And replace

```
$phpjson = (file_get_contents(file_get_contents('icons_ajax.php?alls'), true));
```

with

```
$phpjson = file_get_contents('http://full.path.to/icons_ajax.php?alls');
```

Comment: You may want to use the [file_exists](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function first before getting the contents.

Comment: Just tried with full url. That gave NULL as output, as seen here: http://flamencopeko.net/icons_cogo_21.php

Comment: Dima: I don't. That is how errors are printed. See http://flamencopeko.net/icons_cogo_20.txt.

Comment: Revent: Did try. But I don't think file_exists works on url's like http://flamencopeko.net/icons_ajax.php?alls. And checking if the file itself without the query ?alls exists wouldn't help. I think.

Comment: replace your both 'file_get_content' with one by one and see where is the problem

Comment: Dima: I see now, finally, that there was two 'file_get_content' in the original code I posted. No idea how that happened. I thought you referred to the error output. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

First things first: nesting `file_get_contents()` is almost *never* the right way to solve a problem.

In English, what your code is doing is:

- Read the contents of a local file
- Treat the contents of that file as a path
- Read the contents of the referenced file

This implies that the path you are trying to fetch is persistent, and changes over time. While this is not technically invalid, it's almost certainly a symptom of a bad application design, where a database would be a more appropriate solution,

The next thing to note is without a fully qualified URL (including the scheme and domain) you path is referencing something on the local file system, relative to the current working directory and - crucially - query strings like `?alls` do not work on the local file system. In the context you are most likely trying to use it (`$_GET`) this is a construct of the HTTP protocol.

If you are trying to load some JSON from a remote server, you need to set up your code like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://remotedomain.com/path/to/file.json');
$object = json_decode($json);
// do stuff with object
```

Comment: OP wants to fetch the remote URI with a single fgc call I think https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/LVd7o

Comment: DaveRandom: Thanks. Gave this a try too. But I don't have a *.json file, I have a *.php file. I like flat-file, and would not like to start learning database at this point, although that might seem stupid. Everything is on one server. There are no more than one domain involved or anything like that.

Comment: PeeHaa: Interesting site. I didn't understand it completely. What is fgc call? Found no information on that through Google.

Comment: Is fgc FrameGrabbingControl?

Comment: `file_get_contents()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$phpjson = (file_get_contents(file_get_contents('icons_ajax.php?alls'), true));
```

PHP is not asynchronous, therefore `file_get_contents()` will block until it is completed, and then `var_dump()` will be called, so you probably just do not have a file at the path you specified.